# how to get onFocusChanged in LazyRow for each item?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, android-jetpack

I am working on accessibility implementation (blind disabilities) and once a user swipes left or right in order to move a focus on the item within the LazyRow, I need to know the item index in the list which currently in the accessibility focus.

I have such an impl:

```
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items = episodes, key = { index, _ ->
            "$CARD_KEY$index"
        }) { index, item ->
            item.apply {

            CustomCard(
                episode = item.episode,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .background(
                        BrandedTheme._ui_core__bottomsheet__backgroundColor
                    )
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        if (it.isFocused) {
                            if (listState.isScrollInProgress.not() && selectedEpisodeIndex != -1) {
                                GlobalScope.launch {
                                    listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
                        isTraversalGroup = true
                        traversalIndex = -1f
                    },
                index = index
            )
        }
    }
}
```

So, each item in the list has a modifier with the property - `onFocusChanged`, the problem is that this event triggers only when the list is initializing, but then when a user moves an accessibility focus (by swiping left/right) I see (on the screen) that the next item gets a focus, but in the code `onFocusChanged` is not triggered.

What am I missing here?

**UPD**

Added `onFocusEvent()` and `focusTarget()`, now it seems like I'm receiving the event of changing elements, but there are 2 problems:

1. All elements have the state `Inactive` (none active).
2. The index does not display the index of the element currently on the screen.

```
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items = episodes, key = { index, _ ->
            "$CARD_KEY$index"
        }) { index, item ->
            item.apply {

            CustomCard(
                episode = item.episode,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .onFocusEvent {
                        Log.e("HERE", "111 onFocusEvent: $index :: $it")
                    }        
                    .background(
                        BrandedTheme._ui_core__bottomsheet__backgroundColor
                    )
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        if (it.isFocused) {
                            if (listState.isScrollInProgress.not() && selectedEpisodeIndex != -1) {
                                GlobalScope.launch {
                                    listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .focusTarget()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
                        isTraversalGroup = true
                        traversalIndex = -1f
                    },
                index = index
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Another idea I had was to create a custom `rememberSnapFlingBehavior` because I noticed that in accessibility mode, the focus on the screen switches and it pulls the next element, but it doesn't center it on the screen (although this works without accessibility mode). But in the end, this idea didn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide CustomCard Composable?

Comment: You can increase the chances for an answer if you provide code that is self-contained and can actually be executed. It would also help if you remove all parts of the code that is not relevant to the problem you experience. In essence, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great.

Comment: And while you're at it, please replace the `GlobalScope` by a `rememberCoroutineScope()` that you saved to variable up front. The usage of `GlobalScope` hurts my eyes. :) -- There is a reason why it is annotated as a delicate API.

Comment: Try this library  https://github.com/theapache64/twyper

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, Compose doesn't propagate focus changes to the parent composable by default (in order to improve performance). In your case, you *might* need to manually propagate the focus changes by passing a callback function from the parent composable.

Also, when traversalIndex is set to -1f, I don't believe the item is included in the accessibility focus traversal, which *might* also be part of the problem. Have you tried setting `traversalIndex = index.toFloat()`?

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions and maybes in your answer, it almost seems like random guesses. Can you be more specific or back up any of your assumptions?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).